# CSS Overflow scroll only appears when needed

Tags: css, scrollbar

Hey I have just added the following code to one of my span:

```
overflow-y : scroll;
height: 200px;
```

This is kind of working fine. The only issue is that the scroll bar does appear all the time even when you can't click on it. Isn't there a way to hide it if it is inactive ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set

```
overflow-y:auto;
```

on the element

Answer (score 0):

Set `overflow-y` to `auto`.
This will solve it.